# What causes the Summon command to appear?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

After playing over 40 hours of FFXV, I've been able to summon probably around 10 times. Many times it's during boss fights, but not always. Is there some criteria that has to be met for the ability to summon one of the Six to appear? Or is it just random/luck?

For clarification, I'm not asking what determines which of the Six will appear, I'm asking what influences whether or not I'll get the prompt to summon, *period*.

Answer (score 1):

George Willcox already provided the correct source to this, but didn't answer the question.

The summons become available *randomly*.

As explained in the [Wiki:Astral](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Astral), certain circumstances increase the chance for certain summons.

**Titan**'s chance increases the more allies are KO or in critical health. Also he needs an open area to be able to appear.

**Ramuh**'s chance increases with battle duration and does not have additional requirements.

**Leviathan**'s chance increases when Noctis is in critical health. She needs an open area as well, but also water nearby.

**Shiva**'s chance increases the more allies are KO or in critical health and with battle duration. She also needs space, but it is less restrictive than for Titan and Leviathan.

**Bahamut** is a special case and can only be summoned at a particular point in the story.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the option to summon appeared when me or a member of my party suffered a lot of damage in a short span of time (DPS). If you're the type to immediately use a Phoenix Down on a fallen party member, maybe hold out a while and the summon command should appear!

Comment: Bet it appeared only in very specific battles, not in any battle.

Answer (score -2):

In Final Fantasy XV, once you unlock a summon you'll be given an item that will allow you to summon that monster. Outside of a few scripted encounters you can only use the summons while encountering side quest enemies, in boss battles or during other encounters in the open world.

The Astrals, or The Six, can only be summoned by Noctis Lucis Caelum. And this can only be done after defeating that Astral in battle or by unlocking them through other means to gain their favour.

I hope this answers your question, I've never personally played any of the Final fantasy games so I don't know how accurate this information is.

**Sources:**

- [Wikia - Astral](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Astral)
- [Wikia - Summoner](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner_(job))
- [Game Heroes - How to use the summons](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/use-summons-final-fantasy-xv/)

Comment: Hmm, this makes it seem like I could actually just summon whenever, not just when there's a prompt. I'll test this out and get back to you on that.

Comment: There is an answer on your other question about the conditions for the different Astrals to summon: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293950/are-summons-random

Comment: I posted that question because that answer was originally posted here. It was a good answer with good info but it didn't answer this question really, so I gave it a new home.

Comment: Having checked, you cannot summon at will. It looks like Summoning only works when there is a prompt.

Comment: This answer is very lacking and does not give answer to the actual question at all. You just keep saying "can be done after defeating..." but not **how and when the option to summon appears**.