# Are summons random?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've only been able to summon about 10 times so far, but all but one or two of the times, I've summoned Ramuh. The cutscene is cool, but I have 3 other summons, so why haven't I called on them? Is who gets summoned randomized or are there factors that dictate who will get summoned and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there are certain conditions, which is often based on environment, depending on which Astral it is. Here's an excerpt from a [guide](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/how-summon-astrals-final-fantasy-15-summoning-ramuh-titan-leviathan-shiva-bahamut-572498):

> **Titan**: Chance increases with number of fallen allies. Can only be summoned in wide, open locations or flat terrains.
>
> **Ramuh**: Chance increases with amount of time spent in battle. Can be summoned anywhere.
>
> **Leviathan**: Can be summoned when Noctis is in trouble (during Danger status). Can only be summoned near bodies of water such as lakes or near the coast.
>
> **Shiva**:  Chance scales as the chances to summon all other Astrals increases. Can be summoned anywhere, given sufficient space.
>
> **Bahamut** & **Ifrit**: [Can only be summoned in the late game automatically.](http://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5114-final-fantasy-xv-guide-how-to-summon-the-astrals-to-your-aid)